# Batch file - How do I run an .exe file with a randomized name?

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file run a .exe file after I've downloaded it. The problem is, the name of the downloaded file is randomized upon download (done so from the webpage it's downloaded from). I have no way of guessing the name of the file, so I want the batch file to run the .exe file regardless of what name it may have.

I want it to:

1: download the file - which it does perfectly.

2: then run the .exe file regardless of the name - which doesn't work as intended. (Error; Windows cannot find '*.exe'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again) - I have tried several solutions provided around the web from a mashup of questions - nothing works.

3: delete the file - which it does perfectly.

This is what I got so far:

```
echo Downloading file...
start "" https://TheWebPagesName.com
PING localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo Running file...
start "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername\*.exe"
PING localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo Deleting File...
del "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername\*.exe"
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
echo Done!
PING localhost -n 6 >NUL
echo Exiting...
PING localhost -n 4 >NUL
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any control over where the file is downloaded to? What directory?

Comment: Yes. It is downloaded to "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername"

It is also the ONLY .exe file in that directory, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes it does make a difference, because then you can search for it using forfiles or for, and store its result in a variable. I don't have time to write you an answer right now, but with this information, others will be able to do so.

Comment: In case you want to give it a crack yourself, open a command prompt and type forfiles /?. its not that hard really.

Comment: Would this work?: 

forfiles /p "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername" /m *.exe /c start

Comment: Nope, but the help page shows you examples.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Gonna fiddle with this myself! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: After fiddling for a great amount of time, I've made it locate and give me the name of the file I've downloaded - but I can't figure out how to make it run the file once it has gotten the name of it. The "%variable" and the "FOR" command is a little too complex for me to handle as I only really have 2 hours of experience with batch files.

Comment: The problem with start is that it takes the first parameter in double quotes as the window title, insert a dummy pair directly follwing start ""

Comment: I've posted you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using forfiles.

Forfiles can search for files, and then execute a command and use the files it finds as a variable, or do some checks. Forfiles supports filemasks, and given that you explained that the exefile is the only file in the folder, forfiles can be used.

Your script would look like this:

```
echo Downloading file...
start "" https://TheWebPagesName.com
PING localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo Running file...

:: comment out old row for easy reading    
:: start "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername\*.exe"

:: insert new comamnd instead:
forfiles /p "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername" /m *.exe /c "@file"

:: if you were not using executables, but would want to use start file.txt, you would use:
::forfiles /p "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername" /m *.txt /c "cmd /c @file"

PING localhost -n 10 >NUL
echo Deleting File...
del "C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Foldername\*.exe"
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
echo Done!
PING localhost -n 6 >NUL
echo Exiting...
PING localhost -n 4 >NUL
```

Comment: Thank you! 

It works perfectly. Much appreciated! 

Have a great day :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [aria2](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/releases) to download that file. Then run it. Use this batch script:

```
aria2c.exe --out="FileName.exe" --check-certificate=false --dir="C:\folder\path" "download_link"
"C:\folder\path\FileName.exe"
timeout /t 10
del "C:\folder\path\FileName.exe"
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

However, this only came up with "aria2c.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." - LPChip's reply above works just perfectly, however.

Thanks for your time & reply, once more.

Cheers - have a great day :)

Comment: @H4yw1r3_88 you have to open command prompt where you've downloaded aria2 executable file. Or enter the full path of aria2c in command prompt.